# Compactar arquivos com PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php, arquivo-zip, php-5

Preciso Compactar arquivos usando o PHP porém minha versão é a 5.1.6, tentei somente criar a pasta `.zip` usando o código abaixo, porém, conforme consta no manual essa funcionalidade só está disponível a partir da versão 5.2.

```
<?php

$MD = date('md');
$dado = "Ticker_70_".$MD."_IPCDA.sql";

$Zipar = new ZipArchive();

$Zipar->open($dado.'.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

?>
```

Gostaria de saber se existe um outro método de compactar os arquivos com PHP que funcione para a minha versão atual, através de bibliotecas por fora ou nativa desta versão.

Edit1: Estou usando Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para utilizar ZIP no PHP 5.1 você deve instalar a extensão pecl [ZIP](https://pecl.php.net/package/zip)

O código está certo, basta instalar a extensão.
Como o php é meio antigo, você terá de compilar a extensão por sua conta.

Você pode optar por usar a biblioteca [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/pclzip-downloads)

Answer (score 2):

se você estiver no linux melhor forma com esta versão de php é utilizando o `shell_exec`

```
$dado = "Ticker_70_".$MD."_IPCDA.sql";
shell_exec("zip ".$dado.".zip $dado");
```